# how to edit word comment in c# code (use dsoframer)

Tags: c#, ms-word, comments, office-interop, dsoframer

When I was in use the dsoframer operation word had a problem.

i can add a comment by code like this

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Comment cm = 
word.Comments.Add(word.Application.Selection.Range, "test");
int ctIndex = cm.Index;
```

but how to update the comment content? I can't find any function to do this!

```
word.Comments[ctIndex]..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read:

```
var comments = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Comments;
    foreach (Comment comment in comments)
    {
      var commentText = comment.Range.Text;
      var scopeTxt = comment.Scope.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(commentText);
    }
```

Do not forget to mark it as answer if this solve your problem ^^

Write:

```
foreach (Comment comment in comments)
      {
        comment.Range.Text = "Write a new text here";
      }
```

Comment: By the way, Do you know how to get the page number for a comment?